# Will stash apply still work after a commit?

Tags: git

If I do `git stash` to store my changes, make some other changes and commit, am I able to do a `git stash apply` to merge my previous changes into my latest ones?

I have done a weeks worth of work (still incomplete), but during this time I have been asked to make a small change to another part of the site. 
I have made this small change, and want to commit it without committing my weeks worth of work. I know I can use `git stash` to temporarily store this work, but will a commit overwrite the stash?

Comment: It will. But it's much better to use git branches for long tasks

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at [this article](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/) about best practices in git. It's not directly releveant to your question but should help you in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, yes. `git stash` will persist changes across commits.

I would, however, prefer to perform the above workflow by creating a development branch for your feature, and switch to/patch your release branch when quick fixes are required.

Comment: You can also stash some changes, switch to another branch and merge the changes on the stash there. (e.g. when you noticed you started your work on thw worng branch)

Comment: Ended up using your suggested option of using a branch instead of stash. Thank you!